# Why do I have to redefine ampersand in tabular?

Tags: ampersand

I want to print the numbers 0,1,...,n-1 in a tabular environment. My first attempt resulted in the error `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 19.`. By "hiding" `&` (ampersand) in a construct solves the problem. But this looks ugly. Is there a nice way to be able to use `\whiledo{}{}` programming in a tabular?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,calc}
\newcounter{x}
\newcommand{\ampersand}{\ifthenelse{0<1}{&}{}}
\newcommand{\numbers}[1]{\begin{tabular}{|c@{x=}|*{#1}{r|}}
\hline\setcounter{x}{0}
%
% my first attempt produces error:
%
\whiledo{\thex<#1}{&\thex\stepcounter{x}}\\
%
% no error if above line is replaced with:
%
% \whiledo{\thex<#1}{\ampersand\thex\stepcounter{x}}\\
%
\hline\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}\numbers{10}\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When TeX sees `&`, it ends the current alignment cell; but you cannot start a `\whiledo` process in one cell and end it in a different one. With `\def\ampersand{&}` you're delaying the interpretation to when macro expansion takes place; but you're being lucky, actually.

I wouldn't use `\whiledo`; there are more powerful tools, nowadays.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\numbers}{O{0}m}
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \begin{array}
     {
      |c|
      *{ \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 - #1 } }{r|}
     }
    \hline
    x=
    \int_step_function:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \battha_print_number:n \\
    \hline
    \end{array}
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \battha_print_number:n { & #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\numbers{9}

\medskip

\numbers[1]{9}

\medskip

\numbers[2]{10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

TeX will take care of the arithmetic, so you just specify the end point and, optionally, the start point (default is 0).

A possible improvement is to make the cells to have equal width if the end number is two-digit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\numbers}{O{0}m}
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { #2 > 9 }
     {
      \newcolumntype{B}{w{r}{1em}}
     }
     {
      \newcolumntype{B}{w{r}{0.5em}}
     }
    \begin{array}
     {
      |c|
      *{ \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 - #1 } }{B|}
     }
    \hline
    x=
    \int_step_function:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \battha_print_number:n \\
    \hline
    \end{array}
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \battha_print_number:n { & #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\numbers{9}

\medskip

\numbers[1]{9}

\medskip

\numbers[2]{10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The column type `B` is locally defined to be `w{r}{0.5em}` if the final number is one-digit; `1em` otherwise.

Comment: This makes it clear to me what happens in TeX's "stomach". Thanks!